# How can I override the iPhone's home and sleep hardware buttons?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to override the hardware home and sleep buttons on the iPhone?  I did a lot of research on this, but I was unable to find any definitive answers out there.

I'm not looking to design something malicious, but I was curious about the possibility of doing this for a personal project on my own iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible, the operating system intercepts those interrupts in the kernel and dispatches messages appropriately.

Comment: hmmmm thats strange ... yet m working on it lets see what i end up with :) ... btw thanks for the response

Answer (score 3):

This is possible on a jailbroken device only. There are addons available that in fact "catch" hardware button events. I can't tell you how it works, though.

I suggest looking for "jailbreak" and "home button" with a search engine of your choice, for a start.

Since this is for personal use, jailbreaking may be acceptable.

However on a non-jailbroken device (and certainly for any app that should hit the appstore) there is no way to intercept the hardware button events.